# I'm using ~/bin in my $PATH variable, how can I make unity also display my scripts in there?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, paths

I have some scripts and some starters for programs I didn't install via the Software Center in my ~/bin folder. It is in my $PATH variable and I can use my scripts by pressing Alt+F2 and also directly in a terminal. How can I achieve that I can call them also with unity (pressing Super)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `*.desktop` file say as `myscript.desktop`, add command parameters as you want. In this case your script commands.
   See the below for more details on parameters of .desktop file.
2. Test the launcher file (`myscript.desktop`) by double clicking, if working fine just drag `myscript.desktop` file to launcher bar.

Example : a .desktop file containing following code will launch gedit in name of "My Editor"

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name= My Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/debian-logo.png
```

Note: you can also modify some properties of .desktop file (like command to execute) by right clicking the .desktop file and then go to properties

For a detailed guide, see [here](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/create-custom-unity-launcher/)

Comment: I just put the launcher in ~/.local/share/applications
Thanks for the link

Comment: You do not need to, nor should you, make .desktop files executable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create .desktop files for all of them, according to the XDG Desktop File Specification, and place the .desktop files in the `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` directory.